# How can I find the network bandwidth of D2_V2 machines of Azure?

Tags: networking, azure

How can I find the network bandwidth of various virtual machines in Azure? I'm specifically interested in D2_V2.

Ipconfig isn't showing the limit.

Comment: Azure used to be 100mbps per core, but I couldn't find any updated resource about this. A8-A11 are special VMs that they say it is 10Gbps per network card, so I assume regular A, D, DS, D2, and etc. are at most 1Gbps

Comment: Does documentation show the number anywhere?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this kind of question it is better to ask the provider directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran `iperf` on both linux machines. Turns out the network bandwidth is `2 Gbits/sec`